# C++ std::set with a custom lower_bound

Tags: c++, set, stdset, lower-bound

How would I perform a `find()` or `lower_bound()` function on a `std::set` using a comparator function that is independent of its key such that it still runs in O(log N) time?

Suppose I define a data type `foo` with two variables `x` and `y` and have a `std::set<foo>` that uses `x` as the key value.

```
struct foo {
    int x, y;
    foo(int x, int y) : x(x), y(y) {}
};

struct xCompare {
    bool operator() (const foo& i, const foo& j) const {
        return i.x < j.x;
    }
};

// Within main()
std::set<foo, xCompare> fooSetX;
```

Is it possible to perform a binary search using `lower_bound()` or some other function that compares the values of `y`?

For the sake of this argument, assume that `x` and `y` are unique and independent of each other, and that given two `foo` variables `foo1` and `foo2`, if `foo1.x < foo2.x`, then `foo1.y < foo2.y`. This means that I cannot express `y` as a function of `x`, but is also ordered by `y` within `fooSetX`.

For example, given three `foo(x,y)` values (2,5), (3,9) and (5,10) within `fooSet`, a `lower_bound()` that takes `y = 7` as the search term would return an iterator pointing to (3,9).

Currently, the way I go about solving this is by having two `std::set<foo>`s, ordered by `x` and `y` respectively. Whenever I need to search by `y`, I use the second `std::set`.

```
struct yCompare {
    bool operator() (const foo& i, const foo& j) const {
        return i.y < j.y;
    }
};

// Within main()
std::set<foo, yCompare> fooSetY;

// Inserting elements
fooSetX.insert(foo(2,5)); fooSetY.insert(foo(2,5));
fooSetX.insert(foo(3,9)); fooSetY.insert(foo(3,9));
fooSetX.insert(foo(5,10)); fooSetY.insert(foo(5,10));

// lower_bound() with y = 7
std::set<foo>::iterator it = fooSetY.lower_bound(foo(0,7)); // points to (3,9)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot directly pass a custom comparator to `std::set::lower_bound` - you need to pass it to the *class template* itself, as it will be internally used to maintain the order of the objects *(consequently making `std::set::lower_bound` work)*.

Here's how the [`std::set` template is defined](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set):

```
template<
    class Key,
    class Compare = std::less<Key>,
    class Allocator = std::allocator<Key>
> class set;
```

`Compare` is the **only** ordering customization point that allows you to provide a *function object* that will compare your objects as desired in place of `std::less<Key>`.

There's no way of adding additional ordering predicates to an `std::set`.

---

If you want an additional ordering on your objects that will allow you to achieve **O(log N)** lookups, you could use another ordered structure that is kept in sync with the original one. A `std::set` of pointers to objects in the first set that uses a different comparator could work. Example:

```
class MySet
{
private:
    std::set<Item, Comparator0> _set0;
    std::set<decltype(_set0.begin()), Comparator1> _set1;

public:
    void insert(Item x) 
    {
        auto res = _set0.insert(x);
        assert(res.second);

        _set1.insert(res.first);
    }

    const auto& lookup0(Key0 x) { return _set0.lower_bound(x); }
    const auto& lookup1(Key1 x) { return *(_set1.lower_bound(x)); }
};
```

Comment: Oooh. So in the example mentioned in my question, how would the set be constructed (the actual code, I mean)?

Comment: @MuhammadIrhamRasyidi: whoops, I misread your question - you're already passing a comparator to `std::set<...>`... Well, there's no way of using a different comparator than `yCompare` when calling `std::set::lower_bound`.

Comment: Aw, man. One of my ideas was to traverse the Binary Search Tree manually from root to leaf, but I have no idea how to do that.

Comment: @MuhammadIrhamRasyidi: you could simply iterate through each value `for(const auto& v : fooSetY) { if(v.x == 10) { /* ... */ } }` - could that work for your use case?

Comment: However, that will run in O(N) instead of O(log N). Forgot to mention that in the question - time complexity is also an issue.

Comment: @MuhammadIrhamRasyidi: if I get you correct, the idea is to store the objects somewhere, and then set up another way for further access. (E.g. store your objects in a `std::set`, and then set up a map with a different key-type which hold iterators to the respective elements in the set. (In a database framework, this would be similar to indices)

Comment: @MuhammadIrhamRasyidi: if that's the case, you need another ordered structure that is kept in sync with the original one. A `std::set` of pointers to objects in the first set that uses a different comparator could work.

Comment: @MuhammadIrhamRasyidi: I updated my answer with a possible idea for an implementation

Answer (score 1):

Not with std::set, as @Vittorio Romeo points out in his answer.

There is a [boost datastructure](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html) that can lookup by unrelated members, which you would define like

```
struct foo {
    int x, y;
    foo(int x, int y) : x(x), y(y) {}
};

// helpers
struct x_tag {}; 
struct y_tag {};

boost::multi_index_container<
    foo,
    indexed_by<
        ordered_unique<tag<x_tag>, boost::multi_index::member<foo, int, &foo::x>>, // std::less<int> applied to foo::x
        ordered_unique<tag<y_tag>, boost::multi_index::member<foo, int, &foo::y>> // std::less<int> applied to foo::y
    >
> fooSet;

int an_x, an_y;
// lookup by x
fooSet.get<x_tag>().find(an_x);
fooSet.get<y_tag>().find(an_y);
```